# Seagate HDD Error: Unable to mount and see the data inside it

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ntfs

While mounting my HDD on Ubuntu, it suddenly shows the following error:

```
Unable to mount Seagate Backup Plus Drive- 
"DBus error org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.Failed: 
An operation is already pending"

Unable to mount Seagate Backup Plus Drive:- Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: 
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to calculate 
free MFT records: 
Input/output error NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, 
or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows 
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If 
the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different 
device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). 
Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

In issues like this one of the most helpful tools if you have access to a Windows PC is **`chkdsk`**. I think it should be used as **`chkdsk /f [drive_letter]`** to solve any problems related to MFT. NTFS drives do stuff like this very often.

Or else you can use **`ntfsfix`** from an Ubuntu PC. Make sure you have installed **`ntfs-3g`** first. 
Then run :

**`sudo ntfsfix /dev/your_drive`**

But i'm not sure this'll work in your case. But most of the time it should work. Good luck. :)

Comment: how to install ntfs-3g in UBUNTU.

Comment: @Prasant 'sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g'

Answer (score 0):

Attach the HDD to a Windows machine (or boot Windows) and run:

```
chkdsk X: /f
```

where `X` is the drive letter under Windows.